# Lubuntu - compiling vlc v.1 command make and make install not working

Tags: compiling, vlc, gcc, make

Good day everybody!

So, this is my first topic on Ubuntu's forum, and as a perfect Linux beginner and a non-English speaking student, I'll try to do my best to be the most explicit as I can.

So here's my problem: I recently wanted to install an older version of VLC Media Player because the newest ones are too buggy, and the package I downloaded was in tar.gz. So I found somewhere in the net that in order to install those package, you need to extract it to a place (in my case `/home/cermanialop/Téléchargements/vlc-1.0.1`) than install `gcc` to compile software. After I have done this, I gave in a terminal the path to the extracted files (with the command `cd /home/louis/Téléchargements/vlc-1.0.1`), than I opened the INSTALL file which was included in the package to know what to do.

Here's the content of the file:

```
******INSTALL file for the VLC media player
More extensive information for *nix, Windows, Mac OS X and BeOS users can be
found here: http://developers.videolan.org/vlc/
Bootstrapping VLC
=================
If you retrieved VLC from the git server and do not have a "configure"
script, please refer to the HACKING file.
Configuring VLC
===============
A typical way to configure VLC is:
   ./configure --prefix=/usr
See `./configure --help' for more information.
If you intend to debug stuff, you may want to compile with debugging
symbols:
   make distclean ; ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-debug
We recommend using GCC to build VLC, though some people reported success
with the Intel C compiler (version 8) as well. GCC version 3.3 or higher is
required. On older systems (e.g. FreeBSD 4.x, BeOS), please select a more
recent version manually by setting the CC and CXX environment variables
appropriately while running the ./configure shell script.
Building VLC
============
Once configured, run `make' to build VLC.
Installing and running VLC
==========================
You can install the VLC and its plugins by typing:
   make install
But you don't need to install it if you don't want to; VLC can be launched
from the current directory as well:
   ./vlc
Building packages
=================
To build a Debian package, you need to get the packaging info
   svn co svn://svn.debian.org/pkg-multimedia/videolan/vlc/debian debian 
and then
   dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc
To build RPM packages, copy a spec file from extra/package/rpm and:
   rpm -ba vlc.spec
To build an ipkg package (iPAQ familiar Linux), use:
   ipkg-buildpackage******
```

I have been following all those settings (first type `./configure` to check directory for dependencies, after I run that, it give me this back:

```
cermanialop@cermanialop-R051CX:~$ cd /home/louis/Téléchargements/vlc-1.0.1
cermanialop@cermanialop-R051CX:~/Téléchargements/vlc-1.0.1$ ./configure
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU Objective C compiler... no
checking whether gcc accepts -g... no
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking for egrep... (cached) /bin/grep -E
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking dependency style of gcc -std=gnu99... gcc3
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for ar... ar
checking for ld... ld
checking for dlltool... no
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for C/C++ restrict keyword... __restrict
checking for libs in /home/louis/Téléchargements/vlc-1.0.1/./extras/contrib... no
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc -std=gnu99... ld
checking if the linker (ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... (cached) pass_all
checking for ar... (cached) ar
checking for strip... (cached) strip
checking for ranlib... (cached) ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc -std=gnu99 object... ok
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of g++... (cached) gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc -std=gnu99 linker (ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for shl_load... no
checking for shl_load in -ldld... no
checking for dlopen... no
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking whether a program can dlopen itself... yes
checking whether a statically linked program can dlopen itself... no
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for ld used by g++... ld
checking if the linker (ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for msgfmt... no
checking for gmsgfmt... :
checking for xgettext... no
checking for msgmerge... no
checking for ld used by GCC... ld
checking if the linker (ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for shared library run path origin... done
checking for CFPreferencesCopyAppValue... no
checking for CFLocaleCopyCurrent... no
checking for GNU gettext in libc... yes
checking whether to use NLS... yes
checking where the gettext function comes from... libc
checking for iconv... yes
checking for working iconv... yes
checking for iconv declaration... 
         extern size_t iconv (iconv_t cd, char * *inbuf, size_t *inbytesleft, char * *outbuf, size_t *outbytesleft);
checking for buggy GNU/libc versions... not present
checking for shared objects suffix... .so
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for isatty... yes
checking for sigrelse... yes
checking for getpwuid_r... yes
checking for memalign... yes
checking for posix_memalign... yes
checking for if_nametoindex... yes
checking for getenv... yes
checking for putenv... yes
checking for setenv... yes
checking for ctime_r... yes
checking for lrintf... no
checking for daemon... yes
checking for fork... yes
checking for lstat... yes
checking for posix_fadvise... yes
checking for posix_madvise... yes
checking for uselocale... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking for fcntl... yes
checking for asprintf... yes
checking for atof... yes
checking for atoll... yes
checking for getcwd... yes
checking for gmtime_r... yes
checking for lldiv... yes
checking for localtime_r... yes
checking for rewind... yes
checking for strcasecmp... yes
checking for strcasestr... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strlcpy... no
checking for strncasecmp... yes
checking for strndup... yes
checking for strnlen... yes
checking for strsep... yes
checking for strtof... yes
checking for strtoll... yes
checking for vasprintf... yes
checking for swab... yes
checking for stricmp... no
checking for strnicmp... no
checking for fdatasync... yes
checking for vmsplice... yes
checking for mmap... yes
checking for setlocale... yes
checking langinfo.h usability... yes
checking langinfo.h presence... yes
checking for langinfo.h... yes
checking for nl_langinfo... yes
checking for nl_langinfo and CODESET... yes
checking for connect... yes
checking for send... yes
checking for socklen_t in sys/socket.h... yes
checking for struct sockaddr_storage... yes
checking for library containing getaddrinfo... none required
checking for getnameinfo... yes
checking for gai_strerror... yes
checking for struct addrinfo... yes
checking for va_copy... yes
checking for __va_copy... yes
checking for inet_aton... yes
checking for getopt_long... yes
checking return type of signal handlers... void
checking for cos in -lm... yes
checking for pow in -lm... yes
checking for sqrt in -lm... yes
checking for ceil in -lm... yes
checking for exp in -lm... yes
checking for round in -lm... yes
checking for sqrtf in -lmx... no
checking mach-o/dyld.h usability... no
checking mach-o/dyld.h presence... no
checking for mach-o/dyld.h... no
checking dl.h usability... no
checking dl.h presence... no
checking for dl.h... no
checking for shl_load... (cached) no
checking for dld_link in -ldld... no
checking image.h usability... no
checking image.h presence... no
checking for image.h... no
checking for load_add_on... no
checking for dlfcn.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/dl.h usability... no
checking sys/dl.h presence... no
checking for sys/dl.h... no
checking for dlopen... (cached) no
checking for dlopen in -ldl... (cached) yes
checking for main in -lpthread... yes
checking for clock_nanosleep in -lrt... yes
checking for nanosleep... yes
checking for strncasecmp in strings.h... yes
checking getopt.h usability... yes
checking getopt.h presence... yes
checking for getopt.h... yes
checking for strings.h... (cached) yes
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking xlocale.h usability... yes
checking xlocale.h presence... yes
checking for xlocale.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking sys/times.h usability... yes
checking sys/times.h presence... yes
checking for sys/times.h... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h usability... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/ioctl.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/mount.h usability... yes
checking sys/mount.h presence... yes
checking for sys/mount.h... yes
checking arpa/inet.h usability... yes
checking arpa/inet.h presence... yes
checking for arpa/inet.h... yes
checking netinet/in.h usability... yes
checking netinet/in.h presence... yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking netinet/udplite.h usability... no
checking netinet/udplite.h presence... no
checking for netinet/udplite.h... no
checking sys/eventfd.h usability... yes
checking sys/eventfd.h presence... yes
checking for sys/eventfd.h... yes
checking for net/if.h... yes
checking machine/param.h usability... no
checking machine/param.h presence... no
checking for machine/param.h... no
checking sys/shm.h usability... yes
checking sys/shm.h presence... yes
checking for sys/shm.h... yes
checking linux/version.h usability... yes
checking linux/version.h presence... yes
checking for linux/version.h... yes
checking linux/dccp.h usability... yes
checking linux/dccp.h presence... yes
checking for linux/dccp.h... yes
checking syslog.h usability... yes
checking syslog.h presence... yes
checking for syslog.h... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking for ssize_t... yes
checking for library containing poll... none required
checking dirent.h usability... yes
checking dirent.h presence... yes
checking for dirent.h... yes
checking for nanosleep in time.h... yes
checking for timespec in sys/time.h... yes
checking pthread.h usability... yes
checking pthread.h presence... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking zlib.h usability... yes
checking zlib.h presence... yes
checking for zlib.h... yes
checking for MINIZIP... no
checking unzip.h usability... no
checking unzip.h presence... no
checking for unzip.h... no
checking for HAL... no
configure: WARNING: libhal >= 0.5.0 was not found. Install libhal-dev ?
checking for MTP... no
configure: WARNING: MTP library not found
checking for DBUS... yes
checking for ntohl in sys/param.h... no
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -Wall... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -Wextra... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -Wsign-compare... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -Wundef... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -Wpointer-arith... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -Wbad-function-cast... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -Wcast-align... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -Wwrite-strings... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -Wmissing-prototypes... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -Wvolatile-register-var... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -Werror-implicit-function-declaration... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -pipe... yes
checking if $CC accepts -Os... yes
checking if $CC accepts -O4... yes
checking if $CC accepts -O3... yes
checking if $CC accepts -O2... yes
checking if $CC accepts -O0... yes
checking if $CC accepts -ffast-math... yes
checking if $CC accepts -funroll-loops... yes
checking if $CC accepts -fomit-frame-pointer... yes
checking if $CC accepts -bundle -undefined error... no
checking __attribute__ ((aligned ())) support... 64
checking for __attribute__((packed))... yes
checking execinfo.h usability... yes
checking execinfo.h presence... yes
checking for execinfo.h... yes
checking for backtrace... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 groks MMX intrinsics... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 groks MMX inline assembly... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 groks MMX EXT inline assembly... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 groks SSE2 intrinsics... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 groks SSE inline assembly... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 groks SSE2 inline assembly... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 groks 3D Now! inline assembly... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -mtune=pentium2... yes
checking for LUA... no
configure: WARNING: lua5.1 not found, trying lua >= 5.1 instead
checking for LUA... no
checking lua.h usability... no
checking lua.h presence... no
checking for lua.h... no
checking lauxlib.h usability... no
checking lauxlib.h presence... no
checking for lauxlib.h... no
checking lualib.h usability... no
checking lualib.h presence... no
checking for lualib.h... no
checking for luaL_newstate in -llua5.1 ... no
checking for luaL_newstate in -llua51 ... no
checking for luaL_newstate in -llua ... no
configure: WARNING: lua >= 5.1 not found!
checking for LIBPROXY... no
checking for NOTIFY... no
checking for TAGLIB... no
configure: WARNING: TagLib library not found
checking liveMedia_version.hh usability... no
checking liveMedia_version.hh presence... no
checking for liveMedia_version.hh... no
checking liveMedia.hh usability... no
checking liveMedia.hh presence... no
checking for liveMedia.hh... no
configure: WARNING: The development files for liveMedia (live555) can't be found
checking dvdread/dvd_reader.h usability... no
checking dvdread/dvd_reader.h presence... no
checking for dvdread/dvd_reader.h... no
checking libdvdread/dvd_reader.h usability... no
checking libdvdread/dvd_reader.h presence... no
checking for libdvdread/dvd_reader.h... no
checking for dvdnav-config... no
checking libsmbclient.h usability... no
checking libsmbclient.h presence... no
checking for libsmbclient.h... no
checking for struct _SMBCCTX.close_fn... no
checking for dvbpsi/dr.h... no
configure: WARNING: cannot find libdvbpsi headers
checking for dvbpsi_GenSDTSections in -ldvbpsi... no
checking linux/videodev2.h usability... yes
checking linux/videodev2.h presence... yes
checking for linux/videodev2.h... yes
checking for LIBV4L2... no
configure: WARNING: LibV4L2 support disabled because libv4l2 development headers were not found
checking for LIBCDIO... no
configure: WARNING: CD Reading and information library not found
checking for VCDINFO... no
configure: WARNING: VCD information library not found
checking for cdrom_msf0 in linux/cdrom.h... yes
checking for scsireq in sys/scsiio.h... no
checking for ioc_toc_header in sys/cdio.h... no
checking for LIBCDDB... no
configure: WARNING: new enough libcddb not found. CDDB access disabled
configure: WARNING: the dvb access module requires libdvbpsi
checking for inet_pton... yes
checking for inet_ntop... yes
checking ogg/ogg.h usability... no
checking ogg/ogg.h presence... no
checking for ogg/ogg.h... no
checking ebml/EbmlVersion.h usability... no
checking ebml/EbmlVersion.h presence... no
checking for ebml/EbmlVersion.h... no
checking libmodplug/modplug.h usability... no
checking libmodplug/modplug.h presence... no
checking for libmodplug/modplug.h... no
checking mpc/mpcdec.h usability... no
checking mpc/mpcdec.h presence... no
checking for mpc/mpcdec.h... no
checking mpcdec/mpcdec.h usability... no
checking mpcdec/mpcdec.h presence... no
checking for mpcdec/mpcdec.h... no
configure: WARNING: only static linking is available, you must provide a gme-tree
checking mad.h usability... no
checking mad.h presence... no
checking for mad.h... no
configure: error: Could not find libmad on your system: you may get it from http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/. Alternatively you can use --disable-mad to disable the mad plugin.
```

As you could see, it returns that I am missing something, but as I am a noob in Linux, I don't know what and how I can get it, so I continued to follow the instructions by typing next: make and this give me the following error-message:

```
cermanialop@cermanialop-R051CX:~/Téléchargements/vlc-1.0.1$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
cermanialop@cermanialop-R051CX:~/Téléchargements/vlc-1.0.1$
```

I gave a look into my install folders, and I have noticed that I have no makefile file without extension, as I read somewhere else on the net, there should always be a makefile file without extension at the root of the install folder, in my case, I only have a makefile.am and makefile.in file at the root.

So my question is, how do you CREATE this file in order to make the MAKE command working?
Or am I missing something obvious for the installation?

Many thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read carefully following line from your configure log.

```
configure: error: Could not find libmad on your system: you may get it from http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/. Alternatively you can use --disable-mad to disable the mad plugin.
```

by the way, I suggest you enter following command and try again configure.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmadlib-dev
```

And you need to enter following command before build.

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep vlc
```

Comment: thank you very much for the fast information. Thanks to you I was able to launch the "make" command after installing the dependencies. However, when trying to get vlc installed, I get an error message [collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status] how can I fix this?

Comment: please try as make clean and make

Comment: Hello again, and sorry to come back late; I am having a periode of exams and I come online in my spare time, I have upluaded a file on the following adres: which let you see the problem better: http://textuploader.com/k1wc Thank you.